# Swfit FileManager crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when copying a file a second time

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I'm writing a MacOS application with a process that creates a temp folder in the Application Support directory, generates a few new files in that folder and then also copies some user-specified files into it, and then finally copies the full contents of my temp folder into a user-specified final location. Everything works perfectly the first time you run this export process after launching the app, but crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if it gets run more than once. The application-generated files are always created and written fine, but the crash always occurs when the FileManager attempts to copy one of the existing user-selected files, even though it passes my guard statements checking that the existing file is readable and the destination path is writable. If you re-launch the app, it will again run the first time no problem, but crashes the second.

Here is the relevant code:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
guard let existingINIURL = currentExportProfile!.existingINIFileURL else {
    return (false, "No INI file location provided.")
}

guard fm.fileExists(atPath: existingINIURL.path), fm.isReadableFile(atPath: existingINIURL.path) else {
    return (false, "Could not find INI file at specified path: \(existingINIURL.path) or path is not readable.")
}

guard let outputURL = exportTempFilesURL?.appendingPathComponent("OUTPUT", isDirectory: true), fm.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) else {
    return (false, "Problem accessing temp staging path")
}

guard fm.isReadableFile(atPath: existingINIURL.path) else {
    return (false, "Existing file is not readable")
}

guard fm.isWritableFile(atPath: outputURL.path) else {
    return (false, "Destination \(outputURL.path) is not writable")
}

do {
    try fm.copyItem(at: existingINIURL, to: outputURL.appendingPathComponent("CONTROL.INI"))
    return (true, nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    Swift.print("Failed to copy existing INI with error: \(error)")
    return (false, "Failed to copy existing INI file with error: \(error)")
}
```

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash always occurs at the line:

```
try fm.copyItem(at: existingINIURL, to: outputURL.appendingPathComponent("CONTROL.INI"))
```

And since it's an access error of course it never reaches the catch statement to give me any indication of what the problem was.

Interesting note: Instead of copying with `.appendingPathComponent("CONTROL.INI")`, I tried copying the file with its current name and then renaming the copied file in a separate step. When I did this it seemed to be working at first, but it actually only made it so that it worked maybe 3-4 times before crashing the same way instead of always crashing on the second attempt with the same error, still at the `fm.copyItem` line.

Has anyone encountered any similar issues with FileManager?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the backtrace of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was because I forget I had set a delegate on the default FileManager at one point that no longer existed after the first cycle. After I changed the function that needed a delegate to use its own FileManager instance the problem went away.